# Connecting to MQ manager get MQ error 2495

Tags: java-8, ibm-mq, tomcat8

We have an application that was fully working in staging but when we deploy it on production we are getting MQ error 2495. We are running the application in a Tomcat 8.5 and we are using the same MQ libraries (8.0.0.6). The server OS is Windows.

The code for reading the message from the MQ looks like:

```
MQEnvironment.hostname = queueSettings.getServer();
        MQEnvironment.channel = queueSettings.getChannel();
        MQEnvironment.port = queueSettings.getPort();

        MQQueueManager queueManager = new MQQueueManager(queueSettings.getQueueManager());

        int openOptions = CMQC.MQCBDO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING | CMQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | CMQC.MQOO_BROWSE;

        MQQueue queue = queueManager.accessQueue(queueSettings.getQueue(), openOptions);
```

De full stacktrace of the error looks like:

```
com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2495'.
at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.(MQSESSION.java:2063)
at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.getSession(MQSESSION.java:2103)
at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:207)
at com.ibm.mq.MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:185)
at com.ibm.mq.MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQBindingsManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:230)
at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.(StoredManagedConnection.java:96)
at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:194)
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:758)
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:706)
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:670)
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:145)
at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.(MQQueueManager.java:675)
at com.atlascopco.cpq.connections.MQConnection.readMessagesFromQueue(MQConnection.java:92)
at com.atlascopco.cpq.tasks.ResponseHandlerTask.run(ResponseHandlerTask.java:43)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd64' was not found. For a client installation this is expected. [3=mqjbnd64]
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1202)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ$1.run(LocalMQ.java:272)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise_inner(LocalMQ.java:260)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.initialise(LocalMQ.java:223)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.(LocalMQ.java:1255)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalServer.(LocalServer.java:219)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor10933.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getInstance(JmqiEnvironment.java:656)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiEnvironment.getMQI(JmqiEnvironment.java:590)
at com.ibm.mq.MQSESSION.(MQSESSION.java:2056)
... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd64 in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.local.LocalMQ.loadLib(LocalMQ.java:1146)
... 27 common frames omitted
```

How can I find the issue?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The issue is right in front of you: `UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd64 in java.library.path`. There is a native library `mqjbnd64` required for your driver, which is missing in the production environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in your stack trace:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiException: CC=2;RC=2495;AMQ8568: The native JNI library 'mqjbnd64' was not found. For a client installation this is expected. [3=mqjbnd64]
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mqjbnd64 in java.library.path
```

This is documented on the IBM MQ Knowledge center page "[Configuring the Java Native Interface (JNI) libraries](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q031570_.htm)"

On windows the default location for the libraries are below:

```
MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH\java\lib (32-bit libraries)
MQ_INSTALLATION_PATH\java\lib64 (64-bit libraries)
```

You can specify the location of this library one of two ways (both examples below would be for a 64bit JRE if MQ is installed in the default location, if you are running a 32bit JRE use the `lib` directory instead of the `lib64` directory):

1. With a JVM argument, for example:
   `-Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib64`
2. Via an OS environment variable.  In your case on Windows use:
   `set PATH=C:\Program Files\IBM\MQ\java\lib64;%PATH%`

Comment: We tried this but without any luck. Same error is popping up when configuring the JNI library correctly.

Comment: I manually add the path to the path variable in Windows. So that is correct and cmd can directly access the dll files.

Comment: Without double quotes?  Did you restart the JRE?

Comment: Ok after the restart the error was gone. Now when we send a message to MQ nothing happens. No exception has been thrown in the Java application.

Comment: @JimmyD Do you mean that it is working now?  If my answer helped you with the solution please accept it.  If it is not working what is the issue?

Comment: The problem is not solved yet. The error is gone but the application cannot read or write anything to mq. When the code is writing messages to the queue it does nothing also no exception will be thrown.

Comment: The issue you presented in this question seems to be solved.  Can you open a new question with details of the current issue.  StackOverflow is one question per post.